# Handle customized html form method

Tags: servlets

Say I have a method in a form called **test**.

```
<form method="Test">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How should I implement this in the servlet do invoke this method?

I know we can go to the service method and based on the method type and redirect the call, like how doGet and doPost does, but is there a more direct way doing this?

I heard something like implement a doTest() function somewhere it will be directly called...Which I doubt highly. Also from an interview, and I want to know if the interviewer is providing wrong answers to scare the interviewees.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: This was asked during an interview of mine. I had the exact same question. Why the hell you want to do this?

Comment: I guess they want to see if you're confident enough to call them on bad practices and misinformation.

Comment: Not exactly, since initially, I thought why the hell you wanted to do something that was out of standard and complicated the situation. All in all, I was totally confused about this. But he did gave me some answer saying, you can implement some function in the servlet with some reflection techniques or whatsoever to invoke this. But I thought, regardless what you invoke, service() is always your entry point...Quite a unreasonable question.